# In laravel.Do I need a separate token for Rest API and ordinary web router?

Tags: laravel, rest

Do I need separate token for Rest API and ordinary web route? I'm using laravel. 'cause I saw on youtube that REST API  in api route need to authenticate with token. So I wonder what if I put authentication with token on the ordinary web route and also put auth with token in api route. My brain gonna collapse anytime imagining this. Lol btw im just new in programming.

Comment: It falls down to whichever auth solution you're using. If both your api routes and web routes are using the same auth guard then, no, you shouldn't need to have two different tokens. The best thing I can suggest is creating a new Laravel app and just giving it a go :)

Comment: Aaah now i get it. If  I'm using same auth guard on api routes and web routes then no need different token. So where do i need to put my route for auth functionality(like a function to register&login&logout)?  In web routes right?  Sorry I have so much questions. Lol

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would start by reading the documentation about authentication in the Laravel framework. I find it pretty well written and it presents some interesting built-in authentication methods: [Authentication Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication)

There is no best solution, it really depends on what you need to do, where you wanna store the information, and how much work you want to put into security.

If you want to use the same set of users for the API and the web parts, then maybe yes you would prefer a solution with the same authentication guard and though the same kind of token.

The advice I could give you is to start a new Laravel application and try different authentication methods based on the official documentation. You will quickly see what's the best fit for you.

Comment: Noted. Thank you :)